# Calculating percentage with Grafana/Graphite

Tags: monitoring, grafana, graphite

I'm struggling with calculating the percentage of a list of servers.

What I have is:

```
icinga2.$server.services.Memory_Load.memory-windows.perfdata.memory.value
```

and

```
icinga2.$server.services.Memory_Load.memory-windows.perfdata.memory.max
```

I can't figure out how to calculate a percentage from those values.

Anyone can help me out?

I tried to fool around with `reduceSeries`, `mapSeries` and `asPercent` but always get a query error out of it.

Example I tried:

```
reduceSeries(mapSeries(icinga2.$server.services.Memory_Load.memory-windows.perfdata.memory.*,1),"asPercent",3,"value","max")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

you will be needing four queries to achieve it. You can also do it in one.

```
#A icinga2.$server.services.Memory_Load.memory-windows.perfdata.memory.value

#B icinga2.$server.services.Memory_Load.memory-windows.perfdata.memory.max

#C divideSeries(#A,#B)

#D scale(#C,100)
```

in the end turnoff all the queries visibility except #D

make sure to select unit as percent in Axes tab in left-y axis.

Comment: Graphite encountered an unexpected error while handling your request. divideSeries second argument must reference exactly 1 series

Comment: Try using interpolate(icinga2.$server.services.Memory_Load.memory-windows.perfdata.memory.value)

Comment: Not working either. #A and #B are just showing the value and max of each server. As soon as I enter either `divideSeries` or `interpolate` i get the error

Comment: are they series or constant?

Comment: can you see their indivisual graphs can you share image with me?

Comment: yes, I can see their individual graphs. http://img.picshare.at/1532433929_2018-07-24_14_04_36.png

Comment: and what happen when you apply divideSeries formula??

Comment: why there are 3 series in first screenshot??

Comment: Your second query is returning two series actually that is the problem.. try to delete the duplicate entry in graphite

Comment: $server is a variable which includes every server. You only see 3, there are actually more and the number can vary if new servers get introduced into icinga2.

Comment: or specify it further

Comment: and you want percentage calculated of all in one graph?

Comment: repeat the graphs for the server in templating. go to general tap on panel and set the Repeat panel to server

Comment: and your second query return nothing why??

Comment: I don't know where that option is on v5. Which second query do you mean? Query A and B do give me a result, query c (divideSeries) does not. probably because it is not mapping the series? It should divide value a series a to value a series b. not sure what it does right now..

Comment: send me a screenshot of graph of only query #B. on right there will be an eye which allow you to set visiblity

Comment: The option is in general tab when you edit the panel